# Wrong step for SeekBar and Slider when TalkBack is on

Tags: android, kotlin, slider, accessibility, talkback

I'm working on making my app more accessible. But I run into a problem with SeekBar and Material Design's Slider:

[image: SeekBar example]

What I'm having is a SeekBar (or Slider) with a range from 0 to 100. I defined the step to be 1.

When the TalkBack is on, clicking the phone's physical volume buttons controls the focused SeekBar's (or Slider's) progress and the step is not the same as defined (1). For some reason the SeekBar's step is 5 and the Slider's 10, and I can't find a simple way to change it.

The only way I found is overriding the *dispatchKeyEvent* function, but beside the physical volume buttons there are also gestures, voice commands and who knows what the future hides, so it's not a good way to handle it:

```
fun dispatchKeyEvent(event: KeyEvent): Boolean {
    val action: Int = event.getAction()
    val keyCode: Int = event.getKeyCode()
    return when (keyCode) {
        KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP -> {
            if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                //TODO
            }
            true
        }
        KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN -> {
            if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                //TODO
            }
            true
        }
        else -> super.dispatchKeyEvent(event)
    }
}
```

Any insights and suggestions?

Comment: Nope. The answer of @cactustictacs was the best, yet not what I was really needed. 

Take a look at his answer and at the conversation in reply to his answer and see if it helps. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The general rule with Accessibility services is that you shouldn't try to override the standard behaviour - people who use them expect things to happen a certain way, and they might not be able to easily adapt to whatever your app is doing.

As far as I'm aware, the `step` value is really only about the number of possible values the slider can represent, it doesn't say anything about how it can be adjusted. Like the standard volume controls go from 0 to 100, but if you use your volume keys to control that, it still jumps in fixed increments.

You need to actually touch the bar to get fine adjustment - which you can do in TalkBack too, if you drag on it with two fingers. It'll announce the current value when you stop moving, so you can move a little more if you need to. I can't see any other way to do fine control (the swipe gestures do increments too) so I assume this is how users are meant to do fine adjustment! I can't find any alternative info about it

I see `SeekBar` has a [setKeyProgressIncrement](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsSeekBar#setKeyProgressIncrement(int)) method, if you haven't tried that - maybe you can provide hints to the system. I have a feeling the standard jump size might be system-dependent though, and it might be forced to keep everything standardised, so a button click or gesture always adjusts by a certain amount - that way it's consistent, and developers can't create controls that require too many presses to make large adjustments

I wish I could say for sure, and working with a11y in Android can be a pain at times, but I assume that being able to make precise adjustments to the standard controls is basically covered - and users know how to do it if they need to, like the two-finger drag thing. Hopefully someone with some real knowledge can answer!

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) I know how important it is to avoid overriding the accessibility services. However, it affects many things, especially when the Slider's range is between 0 to 1 (or any small or float range).

Comment: A continous ``Slider`` defaults to a step size of 1, so you need to explicitly set that to 0.01 or whatever if you're using small values like 0.0 to 1.0, or it'll cover the entire range in one step. The accessibility action handler for ``ACTION_SCROLL_FORWARD`` and ``ACTION_SCROLL_BACK`` is hardcoded to jump 1/20th of the steps each time (which is the standard behaviour you probably shouldn't change), but if you only have one step, it rounds up to that. Same thing happens with a physical keyboard though - one step means big jumps! You need to specify a step size if the default of 1 won't work

Comment: That's specifically about the "small values" edge case, but your original question is about wanting to change that default jump size of 5%. The issue is that it's a tradeoff - that value has been chosen to allow people with accessibility needs to manipulate the slider across its range with a maximum of 20 clicks/swipes/interactions with whatever hardware control they're using. They lose the fine control, but moving it more significant amounts is easier. And like I said, there is some provision for fine control with gestures. If you change that jump size, you're making it harder to move far

Comment: I'm definitely no expert on this, but ideally you don't want to mess with the defaults built into the standard widgets - it's standard behaviour that works the way accessibility users are used to. Like you say, there's a lot of moving parts you have to account for (and maintain!) and the standard components do all that for you. If you absolutely have to give people that fine control, you might want to look into changing the UI so it can be set another way, or show different controls if accessibility services are enabled. It's all pretty tricky unfortunately. But it's great you care about it!